# JavaFX DataApp sample Cannot compile and run. Too many errors

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, javafx-8

I am trying to run the DataApp sample. When I Open the all the Projects from the folder, some of them have errors in many java files as you can see below in the image.
[image]

I run the project on Windows 7 64bit, With Netbeans 8.0 Beta, JDK 8, glassfish 4.0

When I try to complie one of the java files containing errors, I get the error below:

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\acer\\Desktop\\DataApp\\DataAppClient -     Djavac.includes=com/javafx/experiments/dataapp/client/DataApplication.java -   Dnb.internal.action.name=compile.single compile-single
 C:\Users\acer\Desktop\DataApp\DataAppClient\nbproject\build-impl.xml:88: The J2SE      Platform is not correctly set up.
 Your active platform is: default_platform, but the corresponding property "  platforms.default_platform.home" is not found in the project's properties files. 
 Either open the project in the IDE and setup the Platform with the same name or add it manually.
 For example like this:
 ant -Duser.properties.file=<path_to_property_file> jar (where you put the property "platforms.default_platform.home" in a .properties file)
 or ant -Dplatforms.default_platform.home=<path_to_JDK_home> jar (where no properties file is used)
 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

What should I do to compile the program successfully?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: The java platform name does not match. Did you migrate this project from an older netbeans version?